# How can I use expandable content in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

Markdown has expandable content option to hide and unhide a block of text or a video. This option most often used in `README.md` that is view through github.

Example [from](https://gist.github.com/pierrejoubert73/902cc94d79424356a8d20be2b382e1ab):

````markdown
<details>
  <summary>Click me</summary>
  
  ### Heading
  1. Foo
  2. Bar
     * Baz
     * Qux

  ### Some Code
  ```js
  function logSomething(something) {
    console.log('Something', something);
  }
</details>
````

[image]

When `>` is clicked it gets expended.

---

Is it possible to achieve same property on org-mode for the `README.org` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Org mode has drawers for this; however, they can't contain headings, but lists and source blocks are fine. Use `org-insert-drawer` (`C-c C-x d`) to insert one (and TAB to hide and unhide its contents when at their top line):

```
:Details:
"Heading"
1. Foo
2. Bar
   - Baz
   - Qux

#+begin_src js
function logSomething(something) {
    console.log('Something', something);
  }
#+end_src
:END:
```

Unfortunately Org drawers are not rendered on Github though: It just strips away the :Details: and :END: part...

Comment: If I notify GitHub related to this can they work around to render in?

Comment: They certainly can. You can try to get them to... :)